# Array of objects send from postman gives me undefined in req.body in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I'd create a schema with some attributes, one of which is an array of objects, when I tried to send it from postman the server side read an undefined object from the req.body.
How I can fix it ?

I've tried to change the way to create an array in mongodb, but it still not work.

POSTMAN-REQUEST

```
{
    "waiter"  : "Pinoscotto",
    "to prepare" :  [{"element" : "Pizza margherita" , "amount" : 1}]
}
```

MONGOOSE-SCHEMA

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id : {type : String},
      n_table    : {type : Number, required : true},
      waiter     : {type : String, required : true},
      cook       : {type : String},
      to_prepare : [{element : String , amount : Number }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have type in one of the key name, underscore is missing in `to_prepare`:

```
{
    "waiter"  : "Pinoscotto",
    "to_prepare" :  [{"element" : "Pizza margherita" , "amount" : 1}]
}
```